# Hive Insert Overwrite Into Partitioned Table using dense_rank/row_number, Values not getting deleted

Tags: hive

I am using this below query to insert overwrite itself

```
with cte as (
  select
   *,
    row_number() over(
      partition by interactionid
      order by
        datestr desc
    ) as rn
  from
    tableA
)
    

Insert overwrite table tableA partition(datestr) 
select 
interactionid,
col1,
col2,
col3,
datestr
from
  cte
where rn = 1
```

While the original table has say 3 entries for interactionid 123456 for 3 different dates
say 8th, 9th and 13th, entry with 8th is getting deleted only with 9th and 13th remains.
What am I missing here ?

Comment: this is impossible. Coould you pls post some sample data ? Check data type of interactionid - and if its a string with spaces which make interactionid unique. I would run the  select SQL without insert and see which ones are with rn=1